# Visual Studio Substitute macro call or Auto keyword use explicit type

Tags: c++, macros

Is there a way to generate raw code from a macro call?

For example we have the following macro:

```
#define LOG(x) std::cout << x << std::endl
```

Now in code we have this:

```
LOG("This is a very cool string");
```

Now I want to simply right click on that macro call and generate code like this:

```
std::cout << "This is a very cool string" << std::endl;
```

Same thing for example with `auto` keyword:
`auto myMap = std::map<int, int>();`

I want to right click on the `auto` keyword and say "Replace 'auto' with explicit type declaration" to make it look like this: 
`std::map<int, int> myMap = std::map<int, int>();`

If someone knows anything about this, I would really appreciate to hear!
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Regarding the first question, I think that some compilers have a mechanism for viewing the output from the preprocessor, i.e. the state of your code after macro substitutions. However, it's been many years since I knew of a specific working example.

Comment: Regarding the second question, I think that you're losing a key benefit of `auto` by "baking in" the current type of a variable. If the type of a container, or the type of a function's returned value, should be changed at any point in the future, code with `auto` will adapt in cases where hard coded types cannot. (This is not to say that someone like VisualAssist won't add it to their list of Refactoring tools. Maybe you should write to them?)

Comment: Convert Macros to Constexpr : https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/vcblog/2018/06/26/convert-macros-to-constexpr/

Comment: ReSharper++ has this functionality.

Comment: Interesting article! Thanks for sharing!